# Use jquery ajax in my Ruby on Rails app to refresh and text_field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

My ruby on rails application it’s for a construction company and in a part of it I have a two models, one is called **Item** (rubro) and the other is called **Budget**. Each item created has its own price. In my budget form I have the option to add different items with their quantity using nested form. In the first column I have a collection_select that works with items id to select an item to add, in the second column you complete with quantity,  and in the third column the idea is display the subtotal value (item price * quantity).

My question is **how can I get the item_id was selected in the collection_select for use to get the item price and show the (item price * quantity) in the subtotal text_field?**

It is possible to do that? I know I could do it using ajax and jquery, but I am very new to these. 
Or could someone give me some other idea of how to do it?

this is a part of my form where I want to do what I said:
**_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= f.fields_for :budget_details, :wrapper => false do |form| %>
                <tr class="fields ">
                  <td class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="col-md-9"><%=form.collection_select(:rubro_id, Rubro.all, :id, :name, {prompt: 'Seleccionar'}, class: 'form-control tooltip-required')%></div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"><%= link_to "<i class=\"fa fa-plus\"></i>".html_safe, new_rubro_path, {:class => "btn btn-sm btn-flat bg-green ", :title => "Nuevo Rubro"} %> </div></td>
                  <td class="col-md-1"> </td>
                  <td class="col-md-2"> </td>
                  <td class="col-md-1"><%=form.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control tooltip-required'%></td>
                  <td class="col-md-2"><%=form.number_field :subtotal, class: 'form-control', :readonly => true%></td>
                  <td class="col-md-1"><%=form.number_field :utility, class: 'form-control'%> </td>
                  <td class="col-md-1"><%=form.link_to_remove '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>'.html_safe, class: 'btn btn-danger'%></td>
                  <br>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
```

I put this in my application.js (rubro = item)

```
$('#collection_select').change(function() {
    var rubro = this.val();
    var data = {
        'rubro_id': this.val(),
}
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url : 'rubros/rubro_price',
        data : data,
        success : function(response) {
            var quantity = $("#rubro_quantity").val();
            var price = response.price;
            $("#price").val(price);
            var subtotal_price = (quantity * price);
            $("#subtotal_price").val(subtotal_price);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

and my rubro_controller.rb

```
 def rubros_price
    @rubro = Rubro.find(params[:data])
  end
```

Comment: "Get" it in what context? Client-side? Server-side?

Comment: Please paste some code as well. Specifically, what and how have you created the form. Also, what have you tried in jquery/javascript so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I am writing pseudo code here, If you will provide your code here then I can help you for the same.

> Please read each line below and put your comments if you need more clarity.

```
Select your item from the select box as you said from "collection_select".
 Call the ajax for item price which you selected or you can take from your page if price presents anywhere.
  You will get the price in ajax response.
 Now you have "Item", "quantity" and "price"(from ajax response).
You can calculate subtotal (price * quantity) and fill text_box.
```

## As per your feedback, I am putting ajax code as per above pseudo:

```
$('#collection_select').change(function() {
  var item = this.val();
  var data = {
    'item_id': this.val();
    }
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url : "/item_price", /*Here in controller you can find price as per item id*/
    data : data,
    success : function(response) {
       var quantity = $("#item_quantity").val();
       var price = response.price;
       var subtotal_price = (quantity * price);
       $("#subtotal_price").val(subtotal_price);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering @umishra. Can you be more specific in your answer? can you show me a more specific ajax pseudocode please?

Comment: Hey, @EmilioCenturión I have put ajax code as per your demand. But I am not sure that will exactly work because I have written with assumption only. Please let me know still you need anything more. If you will share you code base then I can help you better or exactly.

Comment: @EmilioCenturión your question was related to calculating subtotal price, which I wrote for you. Now if you want to more answer then you have to ask a new question. Is it make sense?

Comment: Thank you for the help @umishra